# OpenCV - Smoothing borders

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to stitch multiple image patches to a new and mainly gray background image. The image patches contain colored elements which shall not be changed, if possible. Their shape and color is diverse. Like the new background image the borders of the image patches are also gray, just slightly different, but you can see strong borders if I just go by

```
ImgPatch = cv2.imread("C://...//ImagePatch.png")
NewBackground = cv2.imread("C://...//NewBackground.png")
height, width, channels = ImgPatch.shape
NewBackground[y:y+height,x:x+width] = ImgPatch
```

I tried `cv2.seamlessClone()` ([docs.opencv.org](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/photo/doc/cloning.html)) as explained in this tutorial:

[www.learnopencv.com/seamless-cloning-using-opencv-python-cpp](https://www.learnopencv.com/seamless-cloning-using-opencv-python-cpp/)

The edges are perfectly smoothed, but unfortunately the colors of the elements are changed way too much. I know the approximate width and height of the gray border of each image patch. If i could specifically smooth that area that may be a start and lets the result look already better than what I have. I tried different masks with `cv2.seamlessClone()`, of which none of the tried ways workes. So unfortunately I couldn't find a correct way to blend only the border of the patches so far.

The following images visualize my problem in a very abstract way.

What I have:

Left: Background, Right: Image patch

[image: Left: Background, Right: Image patch]

What I want:

[image: Wanted result]

What I currently get by using `cv2.seamlessClone()`:

[image: Current result]

Any help would be very much appreciated!

**EDIT** As I probably was not clear enough: The real images are way more complex and so unfortunately I can not get reasonable results for all image patches by using `cv2.findContour`... What I am looking for is a method to merge the borders, so you can not see the exact transition of patch to background anymore.

Comment: `cv2.seamlessClone()` will not help you here. It tries to make the object blend into the surrounding of the background image.

Comment: Yes, I have discarded that approach. I am currently trying different ideas like blurring the border with `cv2.GaussianBlur()` or other methods. But so far nothing really looked good. Any good idea which might be the best approach? I am not really an openCV expert...

Comment: How much more complex is your actual case? It is good to simplify when asking a question, but if you simplify too much, you get answers that are too simplistic. Is the background of the patch always the same color gray? Is that background color visible elsewhere in the patch? If not, you should be able to use the blue screen technique (grey screen?).

Comment: Have you solved this? I am encountering with the same problem. I just want to eliminate the border but seamlessClone doing too much! I think @Kunibert just want a "less effective" seamlessClone, just as I do.

Answer (score 1):

```
patch = cv2.imread('patch.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
image = cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

mask = 255 * np.ones(patch.shape, patch.dtype)

width, height, channels = image.shape
center = (height//2, width//2)

mixed_clone = cv2.seamlessClone(patch, image, mask, center, cv2.cv2.NORMAL_CLONE)
```

[image: result]

Comment: That is exactly what I did. But the color changes too much. If possible, I want those elements to stay as close as possible to what they look before the image processing.

Comment: @Kumbert, then why does this look different from the picture in your question?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to find contour in your image patch with `cv2.findContour()` (red spot). Then remove the background of the contour and save the image. You can finally combine the one you saved (red spot without background) with the gray background image with `cv2.add()`. I have combined some code I once played with and the code in OpenCV docs (for `cv2.add()`). Hope it helps a bit (Note the example ads the image in upper left corner - if you want elswhere you should change the code). Cheers!

Example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = cv2.imread('background2.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

height,width = gray.shape
mask = np.zeros((height,width), np.uint8)

_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
cv2.drawContours(mask,[cnt], -1, (255,255,255),thickness=-1)

masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(mask,1,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[0])
circle = masked[y:y+h,x:x+w]

cv2.imwrite('temp.png', circle)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

img = Image.open('temp.png')
img = img.convert("RGBA")
datas = img.getdata()

newData = []
for item in datas:
    if item[0] == 0 and item[1] == 0 and item[2] == 0:
        newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
    else:
        newData.append(item)

img.putdata(newData)
img.save('background3.png', "PNG")

img1 = cv2.imread('background1.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('background3.png')

rows,cols,channels = img2.shape
roi = img1[0:rows, 0:cols ]
img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(img2gray, 110, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
img1_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask_inv)
img2_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(img2,img2,mask = mask)
dst = cv2.add(img1_bg,img2_fg)
img1[0:rows, 0:cols] = dst
cv2.imshow('img',img1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort! Unfortunately I already tried this. I probably was not clear enough, I'm really sorry, but the red dot shall not represent an area with one specific color. The real images are way more complex and so unfortunately I could not get reasonable results for all image patches by using `cv2.findContour`... I need a method to merge the borders, so you cannot see the exact transition of patch to background anymore

Comment: Oh sorry then, I misunderstood the question...hope you find your solution!